# ListView - Clickable (NOT per icon but as a whole view)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener

I try to make a `ListView` clickable. I use an adapter with not clickable items and whenever the user touches the listview I want to show a popup. I don't want to delegate the item click, as I want to catch the complete region of the `ListView` not only the areas of all items. I want the border and so on to react as well. So I simple need something that works like `listView.setOnItemClickListener()` which can't be used with a `ListView`...

My adapter makes it's items unclickable by:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int pos)
{
    return false;
}
```

And I want to react to all clicks on the `ListView`...

**1) OnClickListener (throws exception, not usable)**

using this, will lead to following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
```

**2) OnTouchListener (buggy, at least my implementation)**

I use it like following:

```
 lv.setClickable(false);
 lv.setFocusable(false);
 lv.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
 lv.setOnTouchListener(new TouchClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleClick(View v)
        {
            onClick(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleLongClick(View v)
        {
            onLongClick(v);
        }
    });
```

And I wrote following `OnTouchListener`:

```
public abstract class TouchClickListener implements OnTouchListener
{
    private View view = null;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            handleLongClick(view);
        }
    };
    private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
    private static final int MIN_LONG_CLICK_DURATION = 1000;
    private long startClickTime;
    private boolean moveDetected;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            moveDetected = true;
            cancelLongClick();
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            moveDetected = false;

            cancelLongClick();

            view = v;
            handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, MIN_LONG_CLICK_DURATION);
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            cancelLongClick();
            if (!moveDetected)
            {
                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION)
                    handleClick(v);
            }
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
        {
            cancelLongClick();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void cancelLongClick()
    {
        handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
        view = null;
    }

    public abstract void handleClick(View v);

    public abstract void handleLongClick(View v);
}
```

This works, but it's quite buggy... Like only 2 or 3 of 10 touches are identified correctly... It seems like not being able to distinguish a click from a swipe perfectly...

Comment: ListView extends from View. So you can use   `ListView.setOnClickListener`

Comment: I added something... this does not work for me...

Comment: Use setOnTouchListener. Set up a boolean flag that indicates if you moved on your touch listener. If so set it to false. Then on DOWN set it to true. And on UP check if it is still true. If so then you just clicked it.

Comment: I already tried that... I thought there might be a better way... But I added my solution... Actually, my solution is not working perfectly... I seems like way to much error prone to be not able to distinguish between a click and a swipe...

Comment: in Listview you can make setOnItemClickListener easily...it should make a method onItemClick and there you can do the magic...

Comment: that's correct... But this will lead to that the borders and so are not reacting to the touch... Forwarding the `onItemClick` to a `onClick`would work though... But with the mentioned drawbacks...

Comment: I answered my question... Still, this seems to be a manual work around as I actually don't use the `MotionEvent` `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`... And I was hoping there was another way... As my manual touch listener does not use the same thresholds and constants as the normal `onClick`, `onDoubleClick` and the normal algorithm for distinguishing between touch and swipe... So it's not really perfect...

Answer (score 0):

Following `OnTouchListener` works...

Still, what are good values for the constants in it? The ones I choosed seem to work... But there may be better ones ore even a better solution...

```
public abstract class TouchClickListener implements OnTouchListener
{
    private View view = null;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            handleLongClick(view);
        }
    };
    private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
    private static final int MIN_LONG_CLICK_DURATION = 1000;
    private static final int MAX_TOUCH_DISTANCE_IN_DP = 10;
    private long startClickTime;
    private boolean moveDetected;

    private float startX;
    private float startY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            moveDetected = true;
            cancelLongClick();
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            startX = event.getX();
            startY = event.getY();

            startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            moveDetected = false;

            cancelLongClick();

            view = v;
            handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, MIN_LONG_CLICK_DURATION);
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            float endX = event.getX();
            float endY = event.getY();

            cancelLongClick();

            int maxTouchDistance = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, MAX_TOUCH_DISTANCE_IN_DP, v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            if (!moveDetected || (Math.abs(startX - endX) < MAX_TOUCH_DISTANCE && Math.abs(startY - endY) < MAX_TOUCH_DISTANCE))
            //if (!moveDetected)
            {
                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION)
                    handleClick(v);
            }
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
        {
            cancelLongClick();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void cancelLongClick()
    {
        handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
        view = null;
    }

    public abstract void handleClick(View v);

    public abstract void handleLongClick(View v);
}
```